# load tiff images in tensorflow using tensorflow-io's decode_tiff

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I have a dataset of tiff images and I am trying to load the images from a dataframe having a column of image paths using tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff as tensorflow currently does not have support for it.

tensorflow version: 2.3.0

tensorflow-io version: 0.15.0.dev20201015045556

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df['image_path'].values)

image_count = 86
val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
train_ds = list_ds.skip(val_size)
val_ds = list_ds.take(val_size)

def decode_img(img):

  img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img, index=0, name=None)

  # resize the image to the desired size
  return tf.image.resize(img, [256, 256])


def process_path(file_path):

  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)

  return img

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

When I am trying to run the following code to visualize images:

```
image_batch = next(iter(train_ds))

plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
for i in range(9):
  ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
  plt.imshow(image_batch[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
  #label = label_batch[i]

plt.show()
```

The first line itself is giving this error:

```
Assertion failed: sizeof(tmsize_t)==sizeof(void*), file external/libtiff/libtiff/tif_open.c, line 99

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

And it is running endlessly in the python console.

I have looked at various issues :

https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/957

https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/831

But could not find the solution.

I want to load the images in tensorflow only to make use of tensorflow dataset API to enhance performance, as my dataset is quite large. So, let me know if someone have a better idea how to load tiff supported images in tensorflow.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Try adding this `img = img[:, :, :-1]` below this line `img = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(img, index=0, name=None)` in decode_img function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having issues with newer TF versions? I see that you posted this using TF 2.3.x and TFIO 0.15.x and now TF 2.10.x and TFIO 0.16.x have been released.

Also, are you getting any error message when reading the images in or just when you go to display them? I ask because I'm running into errors when reading the images in using the `.decode_tiff()` function.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32869408)